# How can I see the badges I have on the Android app?

Tags: feature-request, badges, android-app

I find the profiles on the Android app displayed very poorly; just a few top questions and some tags. Anyway, I tried to look up my badges because I recently got a silver one on Arqade but I can't seem to find it on the profile.

It shows up on the profile as a badge dot with a 1 behind it, then the bronze ones follow but if I tap on the badges to check for some more info it does't do anything.

I also tried to check the achievements dropdown but it's not there.

Is it possible to see why I got a silver badge? Does this feature exist?!

Here is the current profile view:

[image: For some weird reason image doesn't work]

Comment: I don't know how you can see it, but you got the silver Yearling badge because you were an active member of the Arcade site for one year. (Active means that you earned at least 200 reputation)

Comment: Alternatively, open the Achievement page, or refresh the feed. Recent badge should be already displayed on your achievement panel. Otherwise... it's another bug.